# iPhone 5 vs iPod Touch for development

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-5, ipod-touch

I am currently developing iPhone apps on my iPhone 4 but I need a larger screen to test and develop on. Rather than buying a new iPhone 5 to test on (as rumour is that the iPhone 6 is about to be announced), I was thinking of buying the latest generation of iPod Touch. I was also thinking that my next phone will be an Android phone rather than an iPhone so thats another reason for the question.

From what I can see [HERE](https://www.apple.com/ie/ipod-touch/specs.html) the only difference between the iPhone 5 and iPod Touch is that the Touch does not have phone capabilities or Mobile Network support. For those I can always use my iPhone 4 so thats not really an issue.

Apart from these 2 features, are there any other features the iPod Touch lacks that I need to be aware of?

Comment: This would probably be more on-topic on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the nature of the apps you're developing. iPod doesn't have telephony and GPS capabilities, so if your app relies on Location Services then iPod is less than optimal (I believe Location Services are still available but only use Wi-Fi for positioning).

On the other hand, having a 4-inch device for testing is essential today, so having iPod is better than not having it.